# Missing background on stackexchange's meta edit section

Tags: bug, edits, design

Editing my post I found that in the "How to edit" and "How to format" sections there isn't a background.

[image: missing background]

This happens too in any other post on stackexchange.com

Comment: There used to be a background, but I think the redesign got rid of it...

Comment: @Shadow - shame this isn't tagged [tag:discussion] :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ lol, or [tag:support] - got Mjölnir for both. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard lol - nice reference - although it would have seemed more natural had you not edited from `gold` ;p

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ gold is so dull...